# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
            RadioListTile(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: selectedRadio,
              title: Text("Doctor" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0)),
              activeColor: Colors.green,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setSelectedRadio(val);
                //print(selectedRadio);
              },
            ),
```

on the  val variable i am getting this error of The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: Try: `RadioListTile<int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing whole Object just pass the id of selectedRadio Object

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
setSelectedRadio(val as int);
```

Comment: I think it is important to get an understanding of why `val` are not being automatically assigned to the type `int` in this case since `RadioListTile` should be a generic with a `T` and the `value` are `T`. So since `value` are an `int`, the `onChanged` should be an `int?` in this case. It might be Dart just being stupid here (going to be improved in 2.18), but the solution is not to type case but instead assign the correct generic to `RadioListTile` like e.g. `RadioListTile<int>`.

Comment: @julemand101 yes you're right. Feel free to write a better answer

Comment: Well, I will do so when it have been confirmed that doing `RadioListTile<int>` actually solves the described issue. I have a suspicion that `setSelectedRadio` requires an `int` and the `onChanged` will make `val` an `int?`.